# How to exclude libraries from File History backup in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-history, windows-libraries

I try to use the built-in File History tool in my Windows 10 Pro to create periodic backups of the important files I'm working on. I do not need to back up folders included into the standard libraries Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos. The Backup tool always includes these libraries into the "Back up these folders" list, and I can't remove them through the visual interface. I also tried to change the config files Config1.xml, Config2.xml stored in these folders:

```
BACKUP_DRIVE:\FileHistory\<user_name>\<computer_name>\Configuration\

C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\
```

, but I could not remove libraries from the backup set (or maybe I did something wrong). It seems, the records for the Windows libraries return to the config files automatically.

Is there a way to exclude the Windows libraries from the built-in File History backup tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is built into Windows, but it was not easy to notice it. We need to click the Exclude folders hyperlink in the File History applet in the classic Control Panel:

[image]

Despite the hyperlink title, the opened dialog allows us to exclude whole libraries:

[image]

Note that we still see the folders from our libraries in the "Back up these folders" list in the Backup options in the new Settings, but those folders are not actually archived!

Answer (score 0):

When I need filehistory to behave - I edit the control files Config1.xml and Config2.xml in the dir %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory.  Because as you make changes to your backups using the GUI - the GUI isn't smart enough to clean out any older, possibly conflicting directions, you previously made.